# instead of clicking 3 buttons, need to click only one button to call click method of remaining buttons

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 3 buttons with different logic in my web page in asp.net, instead of clicking 3 buttons i need to click only one button to call click method of remaining buttons.
How i should write code in code behind .CS

Comment: can you show me some of your code?

Answer (score 6):

Lets create three buttons with same OnClick handler.

Default.aspx:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button1" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button2" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button3" />
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender==Button1)
    {
        //button 1 logic goes here
    }
    else if (sender == Button2)
    {
        //button 2 logic goes here
    }
    else
    {
        //button 3 logic goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button click event of first button, you can call click event of remaining two buttons.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2_Click(this, e);
    Button3_Click(this, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can just call the button method name one by one..like eg:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
      button1_click(sender,e);
      button2_click(sender,e);
}
```